# how to change a button in qml to enable false in a cpp file?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I want to change the enable flag of a button in a qml file from a cpp file without changing the main.cpp, something like this:

qml file: test.qml

```
Button {
  id: bt
  height: 100
  width: 100
}
```

cpp file

```
if (true){ test.bt.enable = false }
```

how can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean *without changing the main.cpp*? could you provide a [mre]

Comment: You can establish c++ qml integration using the context property method that suits the best in this case. other [methods](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-overview.html).

1. Write Q_PROPERTY in your CPP (ex: Q_PROPERTY buttonFlag Read Write Notify)
2. Bind your CPP property with the button enable property. (ex: enable: cppObj.buttonFlag)
3. context property explained [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-contextproperties.html) (this example using `Connections` to bind the property but in your case, you can directly access the QProperty `enable: cppObj.buttonFlag`)

Comment: it works, I added to the my qml enable flag the return of the function and changed the type of return of the function in the cpp file.